# Extract a numeric pattern between two only underscores in string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am relatively new to regular expressions and I am running into a dead end. I have a data frame with a column that looks like this:

```
year1
GMM14_2000_NGVA
GMM14_2001_NGVA
GMM14_2002_NGVA
...
GMM14_2014_NGVA
```

I am trying to extract the year in the middle of the string (2000,2001, etc). This is my code thus far

```
gsub("[^0-9]","",year1))
```

Which returns the number but it also returns the 14 that is part of the string:

```
142000
142001
```

Any idea on how to exclude the 14 from the pattern or how to extract the year information more efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following `gsub`:

```
s  = "GMM14_2002_NGVA"
gsub("^[^_]*_|_[^_]*$", "", s)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/fPMEcL)

The regex breakdown:

Match...

- `^[^_]*_` - 0 or more characters other than `_` from the start of string and a`_`
- `|` - or...
- `_[^_]*$` - a `_` and 0 or more characters other than `_` to the end of string

and remove them.

As an alternative,

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(s,"(?<=_)\\d{4}(?=_)")
```

Where the Perl-like regex matches 4-digit substring that is enclosed with underscores.

Comment: Note that your regex in gsub matches every character that is not a digit and removes it from the input. That is why you had all digits from input left in the result.

Answer (score 7):

Using `stringi` package, the following is one way. The assumption is that year is in 4 digits. Since you specify the digit number, this is pretty straightfoward.

```
library(stringi)

x <- c("GMM14_2000_NGVA", "GMM14_2001_NGVA")

stri_extract_last(x, regex = "\\d{4}")
#[1] "2000" "2001"
```

or

```
stri_extract_first(x, regex = "\\d{4}")
#[1] "2000" "2001"
```

Comment: There is one potential issue with this regex: since it does not account for the context, any last or first 4-digit sequence will be extracted.

Comment: @stribizhev Sure thing. Seeing the patterns in the sample data, I decided to choose this way. If there are some other patterns, this is not the way to go. Thank you for leaving the comment. :)

Comment: You could also use the direct function `stri_extract_last_regex(x, "\\d+")`.  Should be faster since it avoids some checks

Comment: @RichardScriven Long time. Yes, I agree with you! Thank you very much for leaving this comment.

Answer (score 2):

Another option in base-R would be `strsplit` using @jazzurro 's data:

```
x <- c("GMM14_2000_NGVA", "GMM14_2001_NGVA")

vapply(strsplit(x, '_'), function(x) x[2], character(1))
[1] "2000" "2001"
```

`strsplit` splits each element of the `x` vector on the underscores `_` and outputs a list of the same length as length `x`. Using `vapply` we collect the second element of each vector in the list i.e. the year between underscores.

Answer (score 2):

You may use sub.

```
sub(".*_(\\d{4})_.*", "\\1", x)
```

or

```
devtools::install_github("Avinash-Raj/dangas")
library(dangas)
extract_a("_", "_", x)
```

This would extract all the chars present in-between the start and end delimiters. Here the start and end delimiter is underscore.

syntax:

```
extract_a(start, end, string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used R but had deep experience with regexps.

Idiomatically proper way would be to use matching.

For R it should be [regmatches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.htmlhttp://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html):

> Use **regmatches** to get the actual substrings matched by the regular
>   expression. As the first argument, pass the same input that you passed
>   to regexpr or gregexpr . As the second argument, pass the vector
>   returned by regexpr or gregexpr. If you pass the vector from regexpr
>   then regmatches returns a character vector with all the strings that
>   were matched. This vector may be shorter than the input vector if no
>   match was found in some of the elements. If you pass the vector from
>   regexpr then regmatches returns a vector with the same number of
>   elements as the input vector. Each element is a character vector with
>   all the matches of the corresponding element in the input vector, or
>   NULL if an element had no matches.

```
>x <- c("abc", "def", "cba a", "aa")
> m <- regexpr("a+", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[1]  "a"  "a"  "aa"
```

In you case it should be:

```
m <- regexpr("\d{4}", year1, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(year1, m)
```

In case if you can have another 4 digits in a row in the same string you can use [non capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group). Probably like this:

```
"(?:_)\d{4}(?:_)"
```

Sorry, have no chance to test all this in R.